# why is ok to chain jquery effects, instead of using callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, effects

In the jquery documentation is stated that if you want to add a class after an effect is applied on a selection you must use a callback:

```
// Fade in all hidden paragraphs; then add a style class to them (not quite right)
$( "p.hidden" ).fadeIn( 750 ).addClass( "lookAtMe" );

// Fade in all hidden paragraphs; then add a style class to them (correct with animation callback)
$( "p.hidden" ).fadeIn( 750, function() {
// this = DOM element which has just finished being animated
$( this ).addClass( "lookAtMe" );
});
```

However, you can chain two effects without needing to use a callback:

```
$(".something").fadeOut().fadeIn();
```

Why is that? shouldn't you have to use a callback like this, too:

```
$( ".something" ).fadeOut( 750, function() {
   $( this ).fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: Here's an important clue: https://learn.jquery.com/effects/queue-and-dequeue-explained/

Comment: Try chaining an effect which takes time and see what happens.  Basically it comes down to when you want the next thing in the chain applied.  Right away, or after the previous thing is done.

Comment: It should be noted that when no duration is passed to a jQuery animation method, the behaviour is different from where a duration is passed to the method.

Answer (score 5):

From my understanding, when you perform an operation like fadeIn/fadeOut what you are doing is creating a request that gets placed on an internal animation queue, which performs the actions in a FIFO manner.  Others can detail this more, but as it works like this it doesn't require the use of callbacks.

Comment: This is true, and one of the reasons this (admittedly convenient) approach has fallen into disfavour. This is a pretty severe side-effect and a difficult to understand/manage one. The callback approach is fine, but clunky in terms of syntax, which is why people liked jQuery chaining. If this were being implemented today, it would definitely be promises-based, which would make the sequence concise without adding a special queue (e.g. `(await $thing.fadeOut()).fadeIn()`)

Answer (score 1):

Callbacks make sense for asynchronous operations. So the callback is if you want something to happen after the fading is complete. In your case, the subsequent chained `.addClass()` does not wait for the fading to be complete. It happens right away.

Comment: Just to add a bit more: jQuery achieves chains by returning the object in the call. That's why you can chain calls, it's synchronous behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Because, simply put, the call to `.fadeIn` doesn't wait. All it does is add the effect to a queue, then continues with whatever other code you have. What the jQuery documentation is saying is that if you want to add a class to an element once the effect is complete (which they're just using as an example), you'll have to use the callback, which is called at the end of the effect.

Additionally, you absolutely could chain two effects by using callbacks, but it's unnecessary amounts of typing (and developers usually aim to be as lazy as possible). The reason it works to chain two effects together without the callback is that calling `.fadeIn` or `.fadeOut` adds the appropriate effect to jQuery's effect queue for that DOM element. Effects are played from the queue one at a time, in sequence, so no matter how fast you add them to the queue, they'll always play out at the correct speed and time.